# For a Python dictionary, does iterkeys offer any advantages over viewkeys?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, dictionaries have both an `iterkeys` method and a `viewkeys` method (and similar pairs for values and items), giving two different ways to lazily iterate over the keys of the dictionary. The `viewkeys` method provides the principal feature of `iterkeys`, with `iter(d.viewkeys())` effectively equivalent to `d.iterkeys()`. Additionally, objects returned `viewkeys` have convenient set-like features. There thus are strong reasons to favor `viewkeys` over `iterkeys`.

What about the other direction? Apart from compatibility with earlier versions of Python, are there any ways in which `iterkeys` would be preferable to `viewkeys`? Would anything be lost by just always using `viewkeys`?

Comment: *"Apart from compatibility with earlier versions of Python"* - thing is, that's something you could hardly call irrelevant. Otherwise, everyone would be using Python3.2 already

Comment: @vartec It's not irrelevant, but it is obvious.

Comment: but then again, apart from that `iterkeys()` doesn't have advantage over `viewkeys()`.

Comment: @vartec thank goodness he didn't say that's irrelevant, then!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there's no advantage to `iterkeys` over `viewkeys`, in the same way that there's no advantage to `keys` over either of them. `iterkeys` is only around for back compatibility. Indeed, in Python 3, `viewkeys` is the only behaviour that still exists, and it has been renamed to `keys` - the `viewkeys` method is actually a backport of the Python 3 behaviour.

Comment: This does not explain any of the differences

Comment: @SystemParadox the question explicitly doesn't ask exactly what the differences are - OP asks specifically if there is any advantage to using `iter*` over `view*`, and *already lists* the advantages in the other direction.

Answer (score 21):

A dictionary view updates as the dictionary does, while an iterator does not necessarily do this.

This means if you work with the view, change the dictionary, then work with the view again, the view will have changed to reflect the dictionary's new state.

> They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes.
>   [Source](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

Example:

```
>>> test = {1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> a = test.iterkeys()
>>> b = test.viewkeys()
>>> del test[1]
>>> test[5] = 6
>>> list(a)
[3, 5]
>>> b
dict_keys([3, 5])
```

When changes are made to the size, an exception will be thrown:

```
>>> test = {1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> a = test.iterkeys()
>>> b = test.viewkeys()
>>> test[5] = 6
>>> list(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
>>> b
dict_keys([1, 3, 5])
```

It's also worth noting you can only iterate over a keyiterator once:

```
>>> test = {1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> a = test.iterkeys()
>>> list(a)
[1, 3]
>>> list(a)
[]
>>> b = test.viewkeys()
>>> b
dict_keys([1, 3])
>>> b
dict_keys([1, 3])
```

Comment: This is all quite true, but doesn't actually address the question - the OP knows what `viewkeys` does, and is specifically asking whether there are any disadvantages to pretending `iterkeys` doesn't exist.

Comment: @lvc It explains the differences, which could be considered a positive of ``iterkeys()`` - if, for example, you do not want the possibility it getting updated, using ``iterkeys()`` could be more suitable (although the same functionality could be created with ``viewkeys()``). I'm not saying it's a strong reason, but it's pretty much the only one.

Comment: @larsmans One could argue that it was better than silently working on the updated version where you didn't want it to, but I agree it's a stretch. Yes, the short answer is there is no reason to use ``iterkeys()``, which is why it's gone in Python3. However, I thought I'd explain the differences in the hope it made the distinction clear.

Comment: @Lattyware I do appreciate your answer, although it seems not much of an advantage. I can't recall ever encountering the RuntimeError raised by altering a dictionary while iterating, or wanting to, for that matter. Any thoughts on an actual use case?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Pretty much never. It's very rare that you don't use an iterator as soon as you generate it. I'm simply talking possibility here, this is about all the difference you can get. As others have stated, the only real reason to ever use ``iterkeys()`` and friends is when you want backwards compatibility, other than that, dump them.

Comment: It is important to realise that the iterators do not raise a `RuntimeError` for any change in the dictionary; only for a size change. `del test[3]; test[5] = 6` between iterator creation and iteration will not faze it, nor will `test[3] = 91`. Thus it's dangerous.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I honestly thought I'd already put in an example of that, updated, cheers. It makes my earlier point about not working on an updated version invalid, so disregard that.

Comment: CAUTION: doc page for 2.7 say "Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries."  I read this to mean that it is safe to pass a dictview around, and START an iteration later (after making changes), but once you've started iterating, the dictionary cannot safely be changed. If one is not aware of this caveat, one might think that view methods give a way to modify a dictionary while iterating over it. Not safe (in 2.7). Instead, make a list of "keys to remove" while iterating, THEN remove those keys later

Answer (score 16):

Functionality-wise, as you have observed, views are better. Compatibility-wise, they're worse.

Some performance metrics, taken from Python 2.7.2 on a 64-bit Ubuntu machine:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
```

Dealing with an empty dictionary:

```
>>> emptydict = {}
>>> timeit(lambda: emptydict.viewkeys())
0.24384498596191406
>>> timeit(lambda: list(emptydict.viewkeys()))
0.4636681079864502
>>> timeit(lambda: emptydict.iterkeys())
0.23939013481140137
>>> timeit(lambda: list(emptydict.iterkeys()))
1.0098130702972412
```

Constructing the view is slightly more expensive, but consuming the view is significantly faster than the iterator (a bit over twice as fast).

Dealing with a thousand-element dictionary:

```
>>> fulldict = {i: i for i in xrange(1000)}
>>> timeit(lambda: fulldict.viewkeys())
0.24295306205749512
>>> timeit(lambda: list(fulldict.viewkeys()))
13.447425842285156
>>> timeit(lambda: fulldict.iterkeys())
0.23759889602661133
>>> timeit(lambda: list(fulldict.iterkeys()))
15.45390510559082
```

Same results, though less marked; constructing the view is very slightly more expensive, but consuming it is quite definitely faster (15% faster).

For fair comparison with `list(dict.viewkeys())` and `list(dict.iterkeys())`, `dict.keys()` is distinctlyfaster:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: emptydict.keys())
0.2385849952697754
>>> timeit(lambda: fulldict.keys())
7.842105150222778
```

**Summary:** it's a trade-off; better functionality (which you will rarely use) and performance (which will only *very* rarely be significant enough to worry you—if you're caring about such performance matters, you're probably already in the region of needing to work with numpy/scipy) versus better compatibility and muscle memory usage.

Personally, unless already depending on 2.7-only functionality or unless I am absolutely controlling the runtime environment, I would avoid dictionary views in Python 2 code. Even in these cases, my fingers still want to type `iter` instead of `view`, so I let 'em!

Comment: Some of us live ahead of the curve, I know I default just to ``items()`` and friends due to using Python 3.x a lot. I have to be careful when I go back to Python 2.x. To be honest, while 3.x support is a mixed bag, 2.7.3 support is pretty much universal at this point, give or take the odd one.

Comment: @Lattyware: I haven't had that issue because I haven't used Python 3 for any project yet (still depending on Python 2-only things, e.g. Django).

Comment: We are all constrained by the stuff we use. I head Django is getting pretty close to full 3.x compatibility though. Oh, and I forgot to say, +1 for the thorough speed analysis.

Comment: @Lattyware: yep, their investigations as part of Django 1.5 seem to be going well. Looking forward to being able to use Python 3 generally (though naturally there will still be other drags around).

Comment: My fingers agree with yours in wanting to type `iter` - that's actually what prompted my question!

Answer (score 9):

As the name (and [documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)) indicate, the `viewkeys()`, `viewvalues()` and `viewitems()` methods return a *view* of the current elements in the dictionary meaning that if the dictionary changes, so does the view; views *are* [lazy](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html). In the general case *keys* views are set-like, and *item* views are only set-like if the values are hashable.

In what cases would be better to use the standard methods `keys()`, `values()` and `items()` ? You mentioned a very important one: backwards compatibility. Also, when you need to have a simple list of all keys, values or items  (not a set-like, not an iterator), when you need to modify the returned list without modifying the original dictionary and when you need a snapshot of a dictionary's keys, values or items at a moment in time, independent of any posterior modifications over the dictionary.

And what about `iterkeys()`, `itervalues()` and `iteritems()`? They're a suitable alternative when you need a one-shot, constant-space, lazy iterator snapshot of a dictionary's contents that will tell you if the dictionary got modified while iterating (via a `RuntimeError`), also they're very important for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I'm afraid not - ['(dictionary views) are lazy sequences'](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html)

Comment: Minor clarification: item views are only set-like if the values are hashable.

Comment: Thanks. This is the only answer which actually explains the differences.