# Dictionary list examples, definition or understanding

Tags: python-3.x

How do you get a list of all keys in a dictionary? I know this is a response problem so I really have no place to exactly start the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python 3.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python-3-3)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.keys()` method:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> print(list(d.keys()))
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: The question is tagged Python 3, in which `.keys()` won't return a list.  (The OP may not have been using `list` in the type sense, of course.)

Comment: @DSM: Good catch, thanks. I've updated my answer to match and voted to close as a duplicate.