# Why does 2to3 change mydict.keys() to list(mydict.keys())?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I'm looking at an output from 2to3 that includes this change:

```
-            for file_prefix in output.keys():
+            for file_prefix in list(output.keys()):
```

where `output` is a dictionary.

What is the significance of this change? Why does 2to3 do this?

How does this change make the code Python 3 compatible?

Comment: try `d.keys()[0]` on python 2 and then on python 3

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python-3-3

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/

Comment: when the best change would be `for file_prefix in output:`, but py2to3 cannot guess that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Python 3, the `.keys()` method returns a view object rather than a list, for efficiency's sake.

In the iteration case, this doesn't actually matter, but where it would matter is if you were doing something like `foo.keys()[0]` - you can't index a view. Thus, `2to3` always adds an explicit list conversion to make sure that any potential indexing doesn't break.

You can manually remove the `list()` call anywhere that a view would work fine; `2to3` just isn't smart enough to tell which case is which.

(Note that the 2.x version could call `iterkeys()` instead, since it's not indexing.)

Comment: see related issue [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.x, `dict.keys()` returns a `list`.

In Python 3.x, `dict.keys()` returns a view and must be passed to `list()` in order to make it a `list`.

Since the Python 2.x code doesn't need a `list` it should call `dict.iterkeys()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, `.keys()` returns a list of the keys, but in Python 3 it returns a non-list iterator.  Since 2to3 can't know whether you really needed the keys to be a list, it has to err on the side of caution and wrap the call in `list` so you really get a list.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2, `keys` returned a list while in 3 the return of `keys` is a `dict_keys` object.  So if you were dependent on the list-result behavior, the explicit conversion is necessary.