# How to translate dict(zip(range(n), range(n))) to Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I just ran 2to3 on code that looks like this (A):

```
def idict(n):
    return dict(zip(range(n), range(n)))
```

and it generated this (B):

```
def idict(n):
    return dict(list(zip(list(range(n)), list(range(n)))))
```

both `dict` and `zip` can consume iterators, so why this translation?

B seems to be very slow too. Testing with

```
python -m timeit -s "import B as t" "t.idict(10)"
```

with the following results:

```
________________A______B______C___  
Python 2.7.13   2.89   3.82   2.29
Python 3.5.1    2.63   4.34   A
```

ie. from 2.89 usec to 4.34 (+50%) with the default translation.

Questions.. (i) is there a reason I shouldn't use the original code in Python 3? (it produces the correct result, and seems reasonable to me); (ii) is 2to3 the correct tool (we need to run on both 2 and 3 while transitioning ~150KLOC of python)

**Update:** I've added `dict(itertools.izip(xrange(n), xrange(n)))` as algorithm C in the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does 2to3 change mydict.keys() to list(mydict.keys())?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476079/why-does-2to3-change-mydict-keys-to-listmydict-keys)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-xrange

Comment: A dict literal is even faster.

Comment: @Jasper I don't think it's a duplicate. The other question is about the list ctor being added to a `dict.keys()` call in a for-loop context. The reasoning might be similar, but not the same. The other question is also purely about code and not about the tools.

Comment: @JoshLee it better be since one of the range calls is unneeded..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

py2to3 doesn't see the global picture. It just creates some equivalent code, replacing the functions that now don't create lists anymore by adding a `list` wrapper, to make sure that:

- one can subscript the result
- one can iterate on the result as many times as wanted

(it also puts parentheses around `print`, ... but not relevant here)

So it tries to make your code run, but the performance isn't guaranteed like *at all*.

In your example, the list wrapper is useless, as the `dict` consumes the iterator.

So this tool is useful to make code work quickly, but should not be used without comparing to your original code and decide what to keep/what to change.

The tool could probably be improved to:

- avoid wrapping when the iterator is used in a loop
- avoid wrapping when the iterator is passed to an object which takes an iterable as input.

In your case

```
dict(zip(range(n), range(n)))
```

is perfectly fine and runs faster in python 3 than in python 2 because it avoids intermediate list creations, so leave it that way.

a python 2 equivalent of that would be slightly more complex:

```
dict(itertools.izip(xrange(n), xrange(n)))
```

My advice if you have a lot of code to translate (I've been there):

- use `python -3` switch with python 2 interpreter to expose your code and get some warnings instead of having it crash in python 3 (well, it is supposed to warn about Python 3.x incompatibilities that 2to3 cannot trivially fix, but it misses *a lot* of cases, well, it's better than nothing, for instance it finds the infamous `has_key` calls)
- use `py2to3` and *compare* the results with your original code, *decide manually* where to apply the changes
- you can also use multi search/replace with tools like GrepWin to do what py2to3 would do, only with less risks of degrading the performance:

  - search for `iteritems`, replace by `items`
  - search for `xrange`, replace by `range`
  - track down `dict.has_key` calls, `unicode` built-in
  - I may forget some...
- *test and expose* your code extensively with python 3. some things are invisible to the tool and the `-3` option, like when you're using binary mode to read text files and such.

Comment: Are there any better tools?

Comment: @thebjorn the tool is good, the error was originally to use range instead of xrange in python2, I believe

Comment: @OlivierMelançon `range()` is faster than `xrange()` on small lists in Py2 (at least it used to be).

Comment: @thebjorn no tool will be able to guess that n is expected to be small here, though

Comment: @OlivierMelançon that's true I suppose, although not particularly helpful to me ;-)  I've added the "correct" py2 algorithm to the table (it's the fastest).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the advice, both are very much appreciated.

Comment: my pleasure. I have ported more than 10000 lines of code (which is currently running on both python 2.7 and 3.5 right now) and it wasn't so hard to do.

Comment: (the hardest part is when you're using `.pyd` files that don't exist anymore/yet for python 3, but that's very rare now)