# How do I access values from dictionary randomly in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary :

```
Dictionary={
    Key:value,
    #and so on few more keys and values...
}
```

I want to choose "values" randomly from that dictionary.

Comment: Get a list of all the keys, select a random element of the list, and access that dictionary element.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python for the first step, the rest should be obvious.