# get method, keys in a list in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

How do I retrieve the keys from all my users below down here with the get method?

```
anotherDict = {
      'user1':  [842.86917819535, 25.58264089252],
      'user2':  [706.92644963185, 27.22746146366],
      'user3':  [696.60346488317, 25.67540525994],
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)

Comment: You can just use `list(anotherDict)`, see the link from above.

Comment: The reason I specified the get method is that I want to retrieve it by indexing. Inserting the dict method will conflict on this. But with list method it will yes.

Comment: Then I do not understand what you are trying to achieve :) What do you mean by "retrieve by indexing"?

Comment: Indexing by the unique id that that¨s given for all the lists. Like for example list 15:  list(anotherDict.keys())[15]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
anotherDict.keys()
```

This gives you a list:

```
 [ 'user1', 'user2', 'user3' ]
```

With the get method you can get the 'value' of a single element.

Comment: Question has a Python3 tag, so you probably still need a `list`.