# How to compare with keys from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below dictionary :

`{'ram': ('math', 21), 'madhu': ('phy', 22), 'shyam': ('chem', 23)}`

and I want to compare the values of dictionary with User input, but when I say `m.keys()`, it gives output as:

`dict_keys(['ram', 'madhu', 'shyam'])`

To compare with user input, how do I print the keys as keywords only like `ram,madhu,shyam`, instead of printing `dict_keys(['ram', 'madhu', 'shyam'])`?

Comment: Show your coding attempt please

Comment: You could iterate: `for name in m.keys():` and then use `name` to do the comparison.

Comment: list(m.keys())?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)

Comment: what kind of comparison are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a list, use:

```
m = {'ram': ('math', 21), 'madhu': ('phy', 22), 'shyam': ('chem', 23)

for key in list(m.keys()):
     print(key) #etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys like as:

```
 for key, value in dict1.items():
     print(key)
```

Output:

```
 ram
 shyam
 madhu
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
d = {'ram': ('math', 21), 'madhu': ('phy', 22), 'shyam': ('chem', 23)}
list_d = list(d)
print list_d
```

Output:

```
['ram', 'shyam', 'madhu']
```