# Does Django's reverse() function take in a list as a parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-1.11

I need to invoke Django's `reverse()` method to construct a URL for a certain view function `style_specific`. Its entry in `urls.py` is below:

Figure 1

```
url(r'^(?P<jewelry_type>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/(?P<jewelry_style_user>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/(?P<jewelry_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.style_specific,name="style_specific"),
```

I'm also using Algolia, (a search engine) that plugs its own parameters into the constructed URLS, so I need to use `reverse()` to insert placeholders that can then be manipulated by Algolia. This previously worked when I called `reverse` twice --

Figure 2

```
specific_url = (reverse('jewelry:specific_method',args=[model_name,177013,1337]).replace('1337','{{objectID}}')).replace('177013','{{jewelry_style}}')
```

where `model_name` is a parameter passed into the view function constructing `style_specific`'s URLs, and `177013` and `1337` are placeholders that get replaced eventually. However, this approach is a hackish one that will get hard to maintain later. To that end, I wanted to replace this solution with something more flexible, along the lines of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117042/10125284). Ideally, the placeholders/replacements would be determined by a dictionary `replace_parameters` defined like

Figure 3

```
replace_parameters={'placeholder_1':'replacement_1','placeholder_2':replcement_2} #and so on
```

Unfortunately this is where my problem comes in. In Figure 2, the parameters is passed into `args` a hard-coded list. (Or at least that's what the *syntax* appears as) The solution I attempted to overcome this obstacle was to call `replace_parameters`'s keys as a `list` -- that is, `list(replace_parameters.keys())` par [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819250/10125284). (See below)

Figure 4

```
specific_url = reverse('jewelry:specific_method',args=list(replace_parameters.keys()))
```

This approach yielded this `NoReverseMatch`specifically:

Figure 5

```
Reverse for 'style_specific' with arguments '('jewelry_type', 'jewelry_style_user', 'jewelry_id')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jewelry/(?P<jewelry_type>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/(?P<jewelry_style_user>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/(?P<jewelry_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

where `jewelry_type`,`jewelry_style_user` and `jewelry_id` are the keys from `replace_parameters`.

As part of my debugging, I double-checked Figure 1's regex and verified it passed using a different view function. I also verified `list(replace-parameters.keys())` by testing `isinstance(list(replace_parameters.keys()),list)`. I also tried placing brackets around `list(replace_parameters.keys())` but that did nothing either. [Django's documentation on `reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) implies `args` should have a `list` passed into it, but this is not made clear. Thus my question is: *does `reverse()` allow a `list` object to be passed into `args` or must it be hard-coded?*

Comment: Pleas add what `replace_parameters` contains for real (not "placeholders"). And full error message. If this is possible, please make your question shorter.

Comment: `replace_parameters` specifically is `{'jewelry_type':obj.__name__,'jewelry_style_user':'{{ jewelry_style}}','jewelry_id':'{{objectID}}'})` where `obj` is a Django model class. `{{objectID}}` and `{{jewelry_style}}` eventually get overridden by Algolia.

Comment: With `kwargs` attempt error message should differ. What is it?

Comment: `Reverse for 'style_specific' with keyword arguments '{'jewelry_type': 'Metal', 'jewelry_style_user': '{{ jewelry_style }}', 'jewelry_id': '{{objectID}}'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jewelry/(?P<jewelry_type>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<jewelry_style_user>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<jewelry_id>[0-9_-]+)/$']`

Comment: Some one must evaluate `'jewelry_style_user': '{{ jewelry_style }}', 'jewelry_id': '{{objectID}}'`  placeholders within {{}}. `Reverse` function can see only `{{ jewelry_style }}` as string, as it is, which truly does not match `[A-Za-z0-9_-]+` pattern. `kwargs` is the right way.

Comment: In that case, should I modify my regex to allow `{` and `}`?

Comment: Django will not compute those '{{ adsf }}'. Such placeholders are for templates. Outside of templates they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

`replace_parameters.keys()` means `keys`, not values.

Why don't you use `kwargs` which are more specific for named placeholders matching? Especially when replace_parameters is already a `dict`.

```
specific_url = reverse('jewelry:specific_method', kwargs=replace_parameters)
```

And someone must evaluate `'jewelry_style_user': '{{ jewelry_style }}', 'jewelry_id': '{{objectID}}'` placeholders within {{}}. `Reverse` function can see only `{{ jewelry_style }}` as string, as it is, which truly does not match `[A-Za-z0-9_-]+` pattern.

Comment: I tried modifying my regex into something that might work (e.g. `(?P<jewelry_style_user>[A-Za-z0-9_{}]+)`) but nothing came out of that.

Comment: This is not regex problem. Regex is fine. Fix values in your dict. Replace `'{{ jewelry_style }}'` with real value.

Comment: The issue is that Algolia checks for `{{ jewelry_style }}` to put in the real values -- i.e. `reverse()` doesn't directly insert the real values. A workaround I was considering is to simply hardcode the urls, but `reverse()` exists for a reason.

Comment: As you stated in the original question: `does reverse support list/dict arguments` - yes it does. Passing your `replace_parameters` as `kwargs` is just fine. `Reverse` does support this parameter and understands what to do. The problem is inside `replace_parameters` - it contains placeholders instead of values. Which do not match your regex. That's it.