# Getting key from dictionary

Tags: python

I have a this type dictionary

```
   a= {(93, 184): b'\x01*\x00P\xd2\xac2\xdf5\xfeT\xaa\xa7\beb\x80\x10\d01\x1d\xf9=\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\nLy\x16\xd4\xa68.\xc4'}
```

Its key `(93,184)` changes every time.

I want to get my key for example a[x][x]=(93,184)

How can I do this? I am using Python 3.6

Comment: `list(a.keys())[0]`?

Comment: I have this error "Error in argument: '(a.keys())[0]'

Comment: `list(a.keys())[0]`, with `a` defined as in your question, returns `(93, 184)` (at least in python 3, can't remember if python 2 had a different syntax)

Comment: I am using python 3.6 on my project.

Comment: list(a)[0], another way.

Comment: What do you mean by " Its key (93,184) change every time"?

Comment: sometimes it can be (90,102) or (80,120) so i want to get dict's key.

Comment: @lucas_7_94 same error Error in argument:

Comment: @CKocar tested it on IDLE 3.6.5, and it worked great. that's weird.

Comment: `list(a.keys())` should work and return dictionary key as a list.

Comment: You want to **change** a `dict key`, thats not possible. You have to **insert** new key, **copy** value from old key, **delete** old key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not very clear,

Here is how you could get your keys into a list.

```
a= {(93, 184): b'\x01*\x00P\xd2\xac2........'}
b=list(a.keys())
print(b)
```

Hope it helps.