# Access individual elements of tuples of dictionary keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Considering the code snippet below -

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
list3 = ['a','b','c','d']
dct = dict(zip(zip(list1,list2),list3))
print(dct)
```

gives me,

```
{(1, 1): 'a', (2, 2): 'b', (3, 3): 'c', (4, 4): 'd'}
```

Now,

```
print(dct.keys())
```

gives me,

```
dict_keys([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)])
```

How can i access first element of the above list of keys?
Something like -

```
dct.keys[0, 0] = 1
dct.keys[0, 1] = 1
dct.keys[1, 0] = 2
dct.keys[1, 2] = 2
```

and so on...

Comment: that is not a list of keys, but you can iterate over it just like a list an extract the first element

Comment: Covert the keys to a list with `list(dct.keys())`. Then you can use list indexes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My dictionary keys are tuples, How can i need to access individual key elements?

Comment: @DYZ Thanks. Let me try and get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a dict is unordered, and that `dict.keys()` may change order.

That said, to access the first element of a list, as you said, you can use `list[element_index]`. If the elemnt is an iterable, do that again!

So it would be

```
dct_keys = list(yourdict.keys())
dct_keys[0][0] = 1
dct_keys[0][1] = 1
dct_keys[1][0] = 2
dct_keys[1][1] = 2
```

Comment: Starting from 3.6, dictionaries _are_ ordered.

Comment: @DYZ, In CPython only IIRC, but yup (and, TIL, in 3.7 they are [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6])

Comment: As of 3.7, dictionaries are ordered as per definition of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert the `dct.keys()` output to a list, and then the problem reduces to simple list-of-tuples indexing. To convert your `.keys()` output to a list, there are multiple available ways ([check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)). Personally, I find using list comprehension as one of the simplest and most generic ways:

```
>>> [key for key in dct.keys()]
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

And now simply index this list of tuples as:

```
>>> [key for key in dct.keys()][0][0]
1
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This sounds kinda bad performance wise, and less readable than just casting `dct.keys()` to a list with `list(dct.keys())`