# How to convert a dict to an array with the key value to be a new column

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict like this:

```
{'ABC': array([
         [ 0.,1.,2.],
         [ 3.,4.,5.],
         [ 6.,7.,8.]]),
        array([
         [ 0.,1.,2.],
         [ 3.,4.,5.],
         [ 6.,7.,8.]])
 'DEF': array([
         [ 0.,1.,2.],
         [ 3.,4.,5.],
         [ 6.,7.,8.]]),
        array([
         [ 0.,1.,2.],
         [ 3.,4.,5.],
         [ 6.,7.,8.]])}
```

and I want to have a new like this:

```
['ABC','ABC','DEF','DEF']
```

with each key corresponding to each element in the value and get duplicated.

I tried:

```
[(key,val) for (key,val) in d1.items()]
```

but the key didn't get duplicated

Comment: Got some history homework for us to do as well? :) You need to show you've attempted to solve this problem first - Google will help here "Extract dict keys python" and you'll get this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)

Comment: I'm new to Python. I know how to extract key and values but didn't find a way to put them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary has some invalid syntax, but I think you want this:

```
[key for key, val in d1.items() for _ in val]
```

For instance:

```
d1 = {'ABC': [1, 2, 3], 'DEF': [4, 5], 'GHI': [6]}
print([key for key, val in d1.items() for _ in val])
# ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'GHI']
```