# How to understand below C++ code snippet?

Tags: c++, qt

I have this C++ code which I am not able to understand from some time. I need to write an equivalent code in Python.

`eLst` is an instance of structure `tEins`.

```cpp
for(int iEng = 0; iEng < eLst.length(); iEng++)
{
    //loop over connectors
    QList <QString> connKeys = eLst.at(iEng).connectors.uniqueKeys();
    for(int iCon = 0; iCon < connKeys.length(); iCon++)
    {
        QString connName =  eLst.at(iEng).connectors[connKeys.at(iCon)].name;

        //loop over frameports(frames) of connector
        QList <QString> frPortKeys = eLst.at(iEng).connectors[connKeys.at(iCon)].framePorts.uniqueKeys();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Definitions of the structures used in the above code snippet:

```cpp
typedef struct Eins
{
    QString name;
    QHash<QString, tCanController> commControllers;
    QHash<QString, tCanConnector> connectors;
} tEIns

typedef struct CanConnector
{
    QString name;
    QString controllerName;
    QHash<QString, tFramePort> framePorts;
    QHash<QString, tCanFrame> inOutFrames;
} tCanConnector;

typedef struct CanController
{
    QString name;
} tCanController;
```

Comment: What did you not understand ?

Comment: Please provide a working example. In your case even closing braces are missed.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni I am not getting the use and meaning of the keywords used. also the functionality. I just want to know what "at" "uniqueKeys()" does. I tried in google but not getting thorough meaning of it

Comment: You state `"eLst is an instance of structure tEins"`.  That can't be true. `eLst` looks to be a container ([`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?) of `tEins`.

Comment: @Basavaprabhu, you said eLst is an instance of tEIns, but reading the code it seems that it would more likely be a map of <int, tEIns>, and the "at" you don't understand can be used to get the tEIns corresponding to the key "iEng". The "uniqueKeys()" is uses to eliminate duplicate keys in a hashmap. Please correct your question if you want a formal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eLst` would most probably be some kind of sequential container e.g. [`QVector`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html), [`QList`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) `std::vector` or some other variation which is why it's being used in a counter `for` loop sequentially using an index. You can think of it as a list in Python where you can access an element using an index in subscript operator i.e. `list[index]`.

[`at()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#at) is a method that reutrns the element after performing bounds-checking, otherwise, it throws an exception. It is similar to `[]` subscript operator where bounds-checking is not performed.

[`QHash`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html) is similar to the dictionary in Python.

[`uniqueKeys()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#uniqueKeys) method returns the list of distinct keys that exist in the `QHash`. You can think of it as getting all the distinct keys from the dictionary. See: [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python).

Here's the equivalent simplified code in C++11 (might be helpful):

```cpp
for ( const auto& e : eLst )
{
    const auto& connKeys = e.connectors.uniqueKeys();
    for ( const auto& k : connKeys )
    {
        const auto& connName =  e.connectors[ k ].name;
        const auto& frPortKeys = e.connectors[ k ].framePorts.uniqueKeys();
```

Here's the equivalent Python code for your reference (not tested):

```py
for e in eLst:
    connKeys = e.connectors.uniqueKeys()
    for k in connKeys:
        connName = e.connectors[ k ].name
        frPortKeys = e.connectors[ k ].framePorts.uniqueKeys()
```

The above code snippets are only for your reference. You need to convert the code according to your own data structures and Python APIs.