# how to append dictionary keys into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

given a dictionary:

```
entries = {'blue': ' the color of the sky', 'coffee': ' fuel for programmers'}
```

how do I append the keys into a list?

I got this far:

```
results = []
for entry in entries:
    results.append(entry[?])
```

Comment: remove the `[?]`. should be enough. but quicker just to do `list(entries)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

You can access the keys of a dictionary with .keys(). You can turn that into a list with list(). For example,

```
entries = {'blue': ' the color of the sky', 'coffee': ' fuel for programmers'}
keys    = list(entries.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys of the dict is already a list like object. If you really want a list, its easy to convert

```
>>> entries = {'blue': ' the color of the sky', 'coffee': ' fuel for programmers'}
>>> l = list(entries)
>>> l
['blue', 'coffee']
```

If you want to add the keys to an existing list

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> mylist += entries
>>> mylist
[1, 2, 3, 'blue', 'coffee']
```

You can frequently just use the dict object

```
>>> entries.keys()
dict_keys(['blue', 'coffee'])
>>> 'blue' in entries
True
>>> for key in entries:
...     print(key)
... 
blue
coffee
```