# How to storing keys of dictionary as in a list in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to store large number of keys from a dictionary into a list. I tried following:

1.dict.keys().collect() - doesn't work

2.dict.keys() also fails to store it as a list

Please suggest

Comment: `list(dict.keys())`

Comment: Hey @jordanm thanks this worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)