# How can retreive list of all keys in dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in Python with some keys and their values. like-

states = {"Rajasthan": "Jaipur", "Madhyapradesh" :"Bhopal", "Maharashtra" : "Mumbai", "Tamilnadu": "Chennai" }

I want to retrieve list of all keys of this dictionary like -

["Rajasthan", "Madhyapradesh", "Maharashtra", "Tamilnadu"]

How can i do this.

Comment: ```x = [key for key,value in states.items()]```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)

Comment: It's good to ask questions. But please do sufficient google search first. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python. Other resources: [[1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-dictionary-keys-as-a-list/)], [[2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-keys-method/)]. And I got all this from first three results in a single google search!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension as following

```
keys = [i for i in states]
```

or 
using list function that will convert `states` keys to a list

```
list(states)
```

and you will get

```
['Rajasthan', 'Madhyapradesh', 'Maharashtra', 'Tamilnadu']
```