# creating list out of dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, converters

I need to create lists out of dictionary keys. Something like this:

```
dictionary = {"City": "New York", "Population": "idk", "Location": "America"}

for keys in dictionary:
    keys # I need to convert key string to list for base of pandas
```

I can not write it as list = [] because script is iterating through web and loading different keys.

Would you guys help me, please?

Comment: `[*dictionary]`?

Comment: `Keys=list(dictionary.keys())`

Comment: What is the problem you face ? Your code just iterate over the keys, that seems good

Comment: post expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)