# Convert List to dictionary by key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list like this `myList = [[5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 1], [9, 1], [10, 1]]`
and I want to convert it to dict like `{1:[5,6,7,8,9,10]}` the key is second argument of inner list.

I tried below code but it not work.

```
for i in range(len(myList))      
    myDic[myList[i][1]] = [myList[i][1]]
    myDic[myList[i][1]].append(myList[i][0])
```

Comment: Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python

Comment: can you help me without defaultdict

Comment: Follow the answer without defaultdict: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65265106/5929910

Answer (score 1):

this can easily be done with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

ret = defaultdict(list)
myList = [[5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 1], [9, 1], [10, 1]]
for value, key in myList:
    ret[key].append(value)
print(ret)  # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
```

---

if you want to avoid `defaultdict`, [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) helps:

```
ret = {}
myList = [[5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 1], [9, 1], [10, 1]]
for value, key in myList:
    ret.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(ret)
```

note that `defaultdict` is in the standard library; so if you use a reasonably modern python interpreter (with python 3 you are good anyway) you can use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: thanks for answer, what about without defauldict, is there any other way

Comment: @Kocagoz added a version without `defaultdict`. i prefer the first version though.

Answer (score 0):

Declared `d` as the dictionary. Then append the first value into the dictionary using the second value as a key in 2D list.

```
myList = [[5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 1], [9, 1], [10, 1]]
d = {}
for elem in myList:
    try:
        d[elem[1]].append(elem[0])
    except KeyError:
        d[elem[1]] = [elem[0]]
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a defaultdict:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

myDic = defaultdict(list) # values default to empty list

for a, b in myList:
    myDic[b].append(a)

myDic = dict(myDic) # get rid of default value
```

Comment: thanks for answer, what about without defauldict, is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with a `defaultdict`:

```
myList = [[5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 1], [9, 1], [10, 1], [11, 2], [12, 2]]
```

​

```
from collections import defaultdict
​
out = defaultdict(list)
for val, key in myList:
        out[key].append(val)
        
print(out)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 2: [11, 12]})
```

Comment: thanks for answer, what about without defauldict, is there any other way