# How can I extract all keys in a list of dictionaries while keeping all elements? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Suppose I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
list1 = [{'1': 1}, {'1': 1}, {'0': 1}, {'1': 1}, {'1': 1}, {'0': 1}]
```

how can I extract all the keys into a single list? The desired output should look like:

```
li = [1,1,0,1,1,0]
```

I tried to use

```
randlis = [list[i].keys() for i in range len(list1)]
```

This doesn't work since the output includes the type:

```
[dict_keys(['1']), dict_keys(['1']), dict_keys(['0'])]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, you're overwriting the built-in `list` type's constructor by doing so.

Comment: @blorgon Ahh I see. Thanks!

Comment: Well the problem is you've overwritten `list` to act as your dictionary. Which is very very bad practice. If you call your dictionary `dictionary`, then `list(dictionary.keys())` is the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return dictionary keys as a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819222/how-to-return-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chain from itertools:

```
list1 = [{'1': 1}, {'1': 1}, {'0': 1}, {'1': 1}, {'1': 1}, {'0': 1}]

from itertools import chain

randlis = list(chain(*list1))

print(randlis)
['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop over the elements using `list comprehension`

```
[key for _dict in list for key in _dict.keys()]
#['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0']
```

Note. You should not use `list` or `str` `int` etc for naming variables. I have kept it the same in the example so you understand the loop better. Please change your var name to something else.

Comment: Just as a heads-up, OP seems to want those keys converted to `int`, at least according to their desired outcome `li = [1,1,0,1,1,0]` I'd also recommend using descriptive iterator variables here to aid readability.