# In Python 2, what are the performance trade-offs for viewvalues()/viewitems() over itervalues()/iteritems()?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

Obviously, using `values`, `items`, and `keys` is bad practice in Python 2.X in virtually every instance, because you'll allocate an extra list you don't actually need.  Thus, for some time, the recommended best practice was to use `iteritems`/`itervalues`, and to use the built-in `__iter__` if you wanted to enumerate the `dict`'s keys.

With the backport of Python 3's `keys`, `values`, and `items` to Python 2.7 as `viewkeys`, `viewvalues`, and `viewitems`, I'm wondering what the actual performance tradeoffs are of the `view*` family of functions, vs. their `iter*` counterparts.  Is the only reason to continue using the `iter*` functions that you are targeting Python 2.6 and earlier, or can the older `iter*` methods be faster than the newer `view*` methods in certain contexts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an answer addressing `iterkeys` vs. `viewkeys` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10190228/344143

Summary (with a little backstory): `view*` methods are a live view into the data (that will update as it updates), whereas `iter*` and just-plain `*` are more like snapshots.

The linked answerer suggests that while the `view*`-flavored methods may have a minor performance edge as well, there may be compatibility issues with the backport, and recommends continuing to use `iter*`/`*` under Python 2.

My take: if you want a live view and you're under Python 2, use `view*`; if you just want to whip through the set of keys/values/items once, use `iter*`; if you want to hang on to a snapshot of k/v/i for a bit (or iterate in some non-linear fashion), use `*`. Let the performance slide until you pick it up in an inner loop.