# Python dictionary iteration: d vs. d.viewkeys()

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

Having read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783763/in-python-2-what-are-the-performance-trade-offs-for-viewvalues-viewitems-ov/23083560) on the difference between the "iter-" and "view-" methods of dictionary iteration, I'm still curious about the advantages/disadvantages between running `for i in d: ...` vs. `for i in d.viewkeys(): ...`. Is the first snippet just shorthand for the second? Please help this curious and pedantic python lover :)

Comment: I removed the `python-3.x` tag because I believe this is a python2 question?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I forgot that `d.viewkeys` is the python 2.x port of python 3.x's `d.keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point-of-view of iteration, there is no difference, since the `iter` method returns the same type of iterator for both. This makes sense since `viewkeys` returns a *view*:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> iter(d.viewkeys())
<dictionary-keyiterator object at 0x102567cb0>
>>> iter(d)
<dictionary-keyiterator object at 0x102567d08>
>>>
```

The only difference is the small, constant-time overhead of creating the view object.

`.viewkeys` is useful if you want the set-like behavior, e.g.:

```
>>> d1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
>>> d2 = {'a':2, 'b':1, 'c':3}
>>> d1.viewkeys() | d2.viewkeys()
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
>>>
```

If you want to iterate over the keys of a dictionary, just iterate over the dictionary directly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Timings:

```
from timeit import timeit
print timeit(lambda: {i:i for i in range(10)}.keys())
print timeit(lambda: {i:i for i in range(10)}.iterkeys())
print timeit(lambda: {i:i for i in range(10)}.viewkeys())
print timeit(lambda: list({i:i for i in range(10)}))
```

**Output:**

```
0.890981912613
0.622451066971
0.619216918945
1.39578795433
```

The winner is `.viewkeys()` but similar result to `.iterkeys()`, both are good.

#### Iteration Timing:

```
import time
s=time.time()
for i in d:
    pass
e=time.time()
print e-s
s=time.time()
for i in d.viewkeys():
    pass
e=time.time()
print e-s
s=time.time()
for i in d.iterkeys():
    pass
e=time.time()
print e-s
s=time.time()
for i in d.keys():
    pass
e=time.time()
print e-s
```

**Output:**

```
1.90734863281e-06
2.86102294922e-06
9.53674316406e-07
3.09944152832e-06
```

Comment: This doesn't show anything about iteration... these timings are dominated by the time it takes to create the dictionary...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Edited mine

Comment: These timings don't demonstrate much, the dictionary is so small and you are timing a single loop,  that they, again, are probably dominated by the method-call and noise due to your computer's other processes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah you're actually right, i couldn't test it with a bigger dictionary because i am on python 3.6.0, i have to test it on tutorials-point code editor and i tried with bigger dict but tutorials-point doesn't allow it because it is a to bige dictionary for it to handle

Comment: Consider `repl.it` in the future

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for letting me know that site i'll consider using that next time

Answer (score -2):

Consider this exmaple:

```
data = {"a": "123", "b": "456"}

for i in data:
    print i

for i in data.viewkeys():
    print i

print data.viewkeys()
print data
```

Output:

```
a
b
a
b
dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
{'a': '123', 'b': '456'}
```

From the loop prospective,

- `for i in d: ...` will loop through actual dictionary, ex: `{'a': '123', 'b': '456'}`
- `for i in d.viewkeys(): ...` will loop through `list` of keys, ex: `['a', 'b']`

`viewkeys` method will be useful if you need list of keys from your dictionary

Comment: Incorrect. `viewkeys` returns a set-like *view* of keys in the `dict`.

Comment: FYI, it's a `dict`, and `dict` cannot have duplicate keys.